# Shopify CLI - How to start a local server without ngrok?

Tags: shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

My organization blocks ngrok, so every time I run the Shopify serve command, it fails with a connection error.

So is there any way to just start the Shopify local server? that way I can use `cloudfared` to tunnel the local server to a subdomain.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.

Comment: You might want to try https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel. It's an open-source alternative to ngrok.

Answer (score 0):

When I search on google I found no answer to this question.

I  had success running the server without the ngrok.

Here are my steps:

1. Prepare a cloud server, install Nginx.
2. config domain settings, and forward the request to your local port.
3. If you are using a router,  only router has a public IP, so you need to forward the request to your pc. You could config it in the router.
4. then you need to update .env file, update host value
5. Go partner.shopify.com, app settings. put your URL to the whitelist.
6. use npm run dev to start your project.

I also set HTTPS in nginx. Due to ngrok server is far away from my location. so after using this way.  the starting time is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Start the server by

```
npm run dev
```

instead of,

```
shopify app serve
```